# Preventing oxidation of copper(I)

Tags: electrochemistry

By aerial oxidation $\ce{Cu+}$ can easily oxidise to $\ce{Cu^2+}$. Which of the following should be added to $\ce{Cu+}$ to prevent it from oxidation: $\ce{F-}$, $\ce{Mg^2+}$, $\ce{Mg}$ or $\ce{F2}$? 
$$
\begin{align}
E(\ce{Cu^2+/Cu+}) &= \pu{0.15 V}\\
E(\ce{F2/F-}) &= \pu{2.87 V}\\
E(\ce{Mg^2+/Mg}) &= \pu{-2.37 V}
\end{align}
$$

Why it isn't $\ce{Mg^2+}$?

Comment: What would Mg2+ do to prevent oxidation of Cu+?

Comment: Teacher asking this question should get fired. One of the given would indeed prevent Cu+ from getting *oxidised*, but that's not the only thing it would do.

Comment: Ditch all the choices and go with thiourea. It works beautifully, try adding it to a copper(II) sulfate solution (color disappears) or better yet acopper(II) chloride solution (color disappears and a hite precipitate of copper(I) chloride appears which rediscover with more thiourea).

Answer (score 2):

We need a better reducing agent (that itself oxidises) than $\ce {Cu^+}$.
So choose the ones which have greater reduction potential than $\ce {Cu^+}$.
It isn't $\ce {Mg^2+}$ as it cannot oxidise any further hence it has a very low(negative) reduction potential, so it cannot stop $\ce {Cu^+}$ from oxidising.

Answer (score 1):

In one sense none of the options really works.  Metallic magnesium certainly prevents the oxidation of $\ce{Cu^+}$ to $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$, but also reduces $\ce{Cu^+}$ to elemental copper.  To stabilize $\ce{Cu^+}$ for real use a soft-base complexing agent like thiourea.